# Server-side and client-side code management alongside API

Tags: c#, architecture, client-server

Working on a new multiplayer game with an API, I'm struggling with code management and separating the client-side and server-side code. For context, I'm writing everything in C# (Monogame or OpenTK). No Unity here.

Project structure:

```
Server -> Common <- Client
```

The main problem I have is trying to separate the rendering code from the server logic.

I want to provide anyone the ability to define new types of entities. I would have a base class `Entity` and a plugin developer would inherit from this class to define a new entity type. When the server loads the plugin, if the latter tries to load textures for instance, it'll crash because there's no graphics context. Perfectly understandable. I simply don't know how to create a class structure that would allow the plugin to define the rendering logic *and* the server side logic while being completely separated. The `Entity` subclasses also have different logic on client than on the server (e.g. client-side prediction or position interpolation).

Is there a design pattern or a known pattern that could be used to do this?

I tried using components attached to the instances, which worked to some extent, but the plugin developer still has to check if they are on a server or on a client and add the related components. What if the plugin developer tries to add a client side component? I'm trying to do all of this in a statically typed manner (as much as possible).